# Solving this equation with Laplace transform?

Tags: linear-pde

Can this equation be solved or at least put into a form of

$$F( L(u,t,s), L(u,x,s), L(u,y,s))=0$$

Using Laplace Transforms?

The equation: ${u}_{t}={u}_{x} + {u}_{y}~cos(y)$

B.Cs:

$u(x,y,0)=0$

$u(x,0,t)=f(x,t)$

$u(0,y,t)=g(y,t)$

Comment: Is that equation supposed to be $\partial u/\partial t = \partial u/\partial x + \cos(y)\partial u/\partial y$?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/288417) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be that.